# angular: value generated using interval not reflecting in browser using {{}}

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to show the value being changed after each second in the web page, but {{}} is not working.
However, I used console.log, which does show changing value.

Here is my .ts code snippet

```
randomValue: number;
processIncrementValue(){    
this.randomValue = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
console.log("generating random number: " + this.randomValue);
}
// on this function by button press, value starts to change
start(){
console.log("generating random number: start " + this.randomValue);
this.myVar = setInterval(this.processIncrementValue, 1000);
}
```

.HTML file snippet

```
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="start()">Start</button>
<hr>
<div class="row">
<p>my name is: {{randomValue}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind setInterval to scope with the ES6 arrow function `() =>`

```
this.myVar = setInterval(()=>{this.processIncrementValue()}, 1000);
```

When you use `setInterval(function () { doThing() });`, it binds `this` to the `window` object. So in the function `doThing()` if you have `this.doSomething`, your code wants to find a variable in the `window` object called `doSomething`, which doesn't exist.

When you use the arrow function, it binds `this` to the current scope, which is your angular component.

---

From: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

In regular functions the `this` keyword represented the object that called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button or whatever.

With arrow functions the `this` keyword always represents the *object that defined the arrow function*.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

.TS file

```js
randomValue: number; // = 0 if you need to initialize it

processIncrementValue() {
    this.randomValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.processIncrementValue();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

.HTML file

```html
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="processIncrementValue()">Start</button>
  <div class="row">
    <p>my name is: {{randomValue}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow, I have accepted the first answer, but thank you for sharing your knowledge as well, It would be helpful to see an alternative to others.